# Will our creator terminate us when the reason of our existence is no longer needed or completed? Let's take example of AI

Tags: science-fiction, artificial-intelligence, death, philosophy, origin-of-life

### TL;DR :

Let's say we are created to do one thing and we completed that, what will our creator do with us then? terminate / eliminate us?

### Example of Artificial Intelligence :

Let's say we made a AI to train cars travel in a race track, competing with other cars to win the race. I want the car to drive good enough to finish race in 1 hour. Let's say after training this AI model we got the results and we terminate the AI training program.

Now lets our creator made us the AI(*we are AI for our creator, LOL*) to inhabit other planet like Mars. And let's say Elon Musk did that in 2077.  Then will our creator do?

How to know what our creator wants from us? In the Car AI example the car knew that we want it to finish the race but not the terminating condition of "finishing under 1 hour".

Let say we found out what our creator want's from us; should we stop doing that so that we won't be terminated as we finish the work?

---

We are making a sci-fi short film which is related to AI and this kind of philosophy. Your answers will help me plot the film. 
So *thank you guys*.

---

*Note :- I originally asked this [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/81568/52494) but they said ask on "world building site" so here i am hoping for answers ...*

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Sorry, but other SE have little to no knowledge of what belongs here, excepts for an habit of dumping here whatever they don't deem fit for themself. We help with the rules of fictional worlds, not with plot elements. And what a creator will do with its tool is definitely a plot element. You can find more info in the [help].

Comment: Thank you for having me. I understand now what you are saying about this site's "fictional world building stuff" and thank you for your guidance. I will try asking the question in better way later.